# Minimize button closes window

Tags: 16.04

When I press the minimize button the window closes. How can I fix this?
This has just now become a problem. I have had 16.04 since inception. But this problem just started.
But everything works fine and as it should in every other DE.

Comment: And what happens when you press the maximize and close buttons?

Comment: Max and Close function as they should.

Answer (score 1):

What is actually happening here is that the window is not actually being closed but rather minimised to the left dash or favourites bar.

When you open an application, an icon appears in the dash under activities and you will observe a small circular flag to the left of it to show it is active.

If you then click on the minimise button, the item is being minimised exactly as you have commanded but you will note that the flag to the left of the icon in the dash remains in place indicating it is still active.

If you wish to restore it, simply click on the icon in the dock and the application will be restored as before. The application is not closed as such, when restored it will be in exactly the same condition it was before being minimised.

A similar thing will happen if you have the screen maximised and then press minimise.

The way to restore your application to its normal size state is to double click on the application header and it will be restored to its former condition. It can be resized if required thereafter by positioning your mouse pointer over a corner to drag it to size in the usual convention.

Comment: I have a feeling you are talking about a Unity desktop. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not specifically. But that is the way it works in Ubuntu 18.04 using the Gnome desktop.

Comment: However, I'm using GNOME FLASHBACK (Metacity) and I don't see the things which you are talking about. I should mention that COMPIZ, MATE, GNOME CLASSIC to mention some DE's that I have the option to use all work fine. But METACITY has gone out to lunch on me. But it's not only browser windows, but any window I have open and then press the minimize button. They just go away or actually close.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this question, which would have been easier had I known how to post with correct wording, in this Unix & Linux question: [GNOME: Bottom task bar is missing/blank after upgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178421/gnome-bottom-task-bar-is-missing-blank-after-upgrade)

And the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178423) was:

> It turns out that for some reason the settings for my bottom panel(taskbar) had been altered. To access the menu for the panels(top & bottom bars), I needed to hold Alt and then Right-click. This opened a little menu where I could select Add to panel... which opens another menu of things you can add to the taskbar. What I needed to add was **'Windows List'**, which solved my problem.